# MongoRepository Save method does not insert in database

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, swagger, jhipster

I have created a SpringBoot project with Jhipster. The database I am using is MongoDB.

In the application-dev.yml I have the following configuration:

```
data:
mongodb:
  uri: mongodb://<user>:<pass>@<ip>:<port>
  database: gateway
```

The user, password, ip Address, and port, in my application-dev are real values.

The DatabaseConfiguration.java is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories("es.second.cdti.repository")
@Profile("!" + JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_CLOUD)
@Import(value = MongoAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableMongoAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "springSecurityAuditorAware")
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseConfiguration.class);

    @Bean
    public ValidatingMongoEventListener validatingMongoEventListener() {
        return new ValidatingMongoEventListener(validator());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoCustomConversions customConversions() {
        List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
        converters.add(DateToZonedDateTimeConverter.INSTANCE);
        converters.add(ZonedDateTimeToDateConverter.INSTANCE);
        return new MongoCustomConversions(converters);
    }

    @Bean
    public Mongobee mongobee(MongoClient mongoClient, MongoTemplate mongoTemplate, MongoProperties mongoProperties) {
        log.debug("Configuring Mongobee");
        Mongobee mongobee = new Mongobee(mongoClient);
        mongobee.setDbName(mongoProperties.getMongoClientDatabase());
        mongobee.setMongoTemplate(mongoTemplate);
        // package to scan for migrations
        mongobee.setChangeLogsScanPackage("es.second.cdti.config.dbmigrations");
        mongobee.setEnabled(true);
        return mongobee;
    }}
```

The CloudDatabaseConfiguration is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories("es.second.cdti.repository")
@Profile(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_CLOUD)
public class CloudDatabaseConfiguration extends AbstractCloudConfig {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CloudDatabaseConfiguration.class);

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoFactory() {
        return connectionFactory().mongoDbFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public ValidatingMongoEventListener validatingMongoEventListener() {
        return new ValidatingMongoEventListener(validator());
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoCustomConversions customConversions() {
        List<Converter<?, ?>> converterList = new ArrayList<>();
        converterList.add(DateToZonedDateTimeConverter.INSTANCE);
        converterList.add(ZonedDateTimeToDateConverter.INSTANCE);
        converterList.add(DurationToLongConverter.INSTANCE);
        return new MongoCustomConversions(converterList);
    }

    @Bean
    public Mongobee mongobee(MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory, MongoTemplate mongoTemplate, Cloud cloud) {
        log.debug("Configuring Cloud Mongobee");
        List<ServiceInfo> matchingServiceInfos = cloud.getServiceInfos(MongoDbFactory.class);

        if (matchingServiceInfos.size() != 1) {
            throw new CloudException("No unique service matching MongoDbFactory found. Expected 1, found "
                + matchingServiceInfos.size());
        }
        MongoServiceInfo info = (MongoServiceInfo) matchingServiceInfos.get(0);
        Mongobee mongobee = new Mongobee(info.getUri());
        mongobee.setDbName(mongoDbFactory.getDb().getName());
        mongobee.setMongoTemplate(mongoTemplate);
        // package to scan for migrations
        mongobee.setChangeLogsScanPackage("es.second.cdti.config.dbmigrations");
        mongobee.setEnabled(true);
        return mongobee;
    }
}
```

The cdtiApp.java is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ApplicationProperties.class})
public class CdtiApp  implements InitializingBean{

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CdtiApp.class);

    private final Environment env;

    public CdtiApp(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    /**
     * Initializes cdti.
     * <p>
     * Spring profiles can be configured with a program argument --spring.profiles.active=your-active-profile
     * <p>
     * You can find more information on how profiles work with JHipster on <a href="https://www.jhipster.tech/profiles/">https://www.jhipster.tech/profiles/</a>.
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void initApplication() {
        Collection<String> activeProfiles = Arrays.asList(env.getActiveProfiles());
        if (activeProfiles.contains(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT) && activeProfiles.contains(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_PRODUCTION)) {
            log.error("You have misconfigured your application! It should not run " +
                "with both the 'dev' and 'prod' profiles at the same time.");
        }
        if (activeProfiles.contains(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT) && activeProfiles.contains(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_CLOUD)) {
            log.error("You have misconfigured your application! It should not " +
                "run with both the 'dev' and 'cloud' profiles at the same time.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Main method, used to run the application.
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(CdtiApp.class);
        DefaultProfileUtil.addDefaultProfile(app);
        Environment env = app.run(args).getEnvironment();
        logApplicationStartup(env);
    }

    private static void logApplicationStartup(Environment env) {
        String protocol = "http";
        if (env.getProperty("server.ssl.key-store") != null) {
            protocol = "https";
        }
        String serverPort = env.getProperty("server.port");
        String contextPath = env.getProperty("server.servlet.context-path");
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(contextPath)) {
            contextPath = "/";
        }
        String hostAddress = "localhost";
        try {
            hostAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            log.warn("The host name could not be determined, using `localhost` as fallback");
        }
        log.info("\n----------------------------------------------------------\n\t" +
                "Application '{}' is running! Access URLs:\n\t" +
                "Local: \t\t{}://localhost:{}{}\n\t" +
                "External: \t{}://{}:{}{}\n\t" +
                "Profile(s): \t{}\n----------------------------------------------------------",
            env.getProperty("spring.application.name"),
            protocol,
            serverPort,
            contextPath,
            protocol,
            hostAddress,
            serverPort,
            contextPath,
            env.getActiveProfiles());

        String configServerStatus = env.getProperty("configserver.status");
        if (configServerStatus == null) {
            configServerStatus = "Not found or not setup for this application";
        }
        log.info("\n----------------------------------------------------------\n\t" +
                "Config Server: \t{}\n----------------------------------------------------------", configServerStatus);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
}
```

The Vehicle entity:

```
@org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document(collection = "vehicle")
public class Vehicle implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String id;
    
    @NotNull
    @Field("plate")
    private String plate;
    
    @NotNull
    @Field("registrationDate")
    private Instant registrationDate;
    
    @NotNull
    @Field("brand")
    private String brand;
    
    @NotNull
    @Field("model")
    private String model;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPlate() {
        return plate;
    }

    public void setPlate(String plate) {
        this.plate = plate;
    }

    public Instant getRegistrationDate() {
        return registrationDate;
    }

    public void setRegistrationDate(Instant registrationDate) {
        this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }    

}
```

The VehicleDTO is:

```
public class VehicleDTO {

    private String id;
    
    private String plate;
    
    private Instant registrationDate;
    
    private String brand;
    
    private String model;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPlate() {
        return plate;
    }

    public void setPlate(String plate) {
        this.plate = plate;
    }

    public Instant getRegistrationDate() {
        return registrationDate;
    }

    public void setRegistrationDate(Instant registrationDate) {
        this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
    
    
}
```

The VehicleMapper is:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface VehicleMapper{

    Vehicle toEntity(VehicleDTO source);
    VehicleDTO toDto(Vehicle target);
}
```

The VehicleResource is:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", methods = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public class VehicleResource {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VehicleResource.class);

    @Value("${jhipster.clientApp.name}")
    private String applicationName;

    @Autowired
    private final VehicleService vehicleService;

    public VehicleResource(VehicleService vehicleService) {
        this.vehicleService = vehicleService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/vehicle")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority(\"" + AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN + "\")")
    public ResponseEntity<Vehicle> createVehicle(@Valid @RequestBody VehicleDTO vehicleDTO) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to save Vehicle : {}", vehicleDTO);

        Vehicle newVehicle = vehicleService.createVehicle(vehicleDTO);

        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/vehicle/" + newVehicle.getPlate()))
                .headers(HeaderUtil.createAlert(applicationName, "vehicleManagement.created", newVehicle.getPlate()))
                .body(newVehicle);

    }
}
```

The VehicleService interface is:

```
public interface VehicleService {

    Vehicle createVehicle(VehicleDTO vehicleDTO);
}
```

The VehicleServiceImpl is:

```
@Service
public class VehicleServiceImpl implements VehicleService{
    
    @Autowired
    private final VehicleRepository vehicleRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private final VehicleMapper mapper;
        
    public VehicleServiceImpl(VehicleRepository vehicleRepository, VehicleMapper mapper) {
        this.vehicleRepository = vehicleRepository;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VehicleServiceImpl.class);

    @Override
    public Vehicle createVehicle(VehicleDTO vehicleDTO) {
        
        Vehicle vehicle = vehicleRepository.save(mapper.toEntity(vehicleDTO));
        log.debug("Created Information for vehicle: {}", vehicle);
        
        return vehicle; 
    }
    

}
```

The VehicleRepository interface is:

```
/**
 * Spring Data MongoDB repository for the {@link Vehicle} entity.
 */
@Repository
public interface VehicleRepository extends MongoRepository<Vehicle, String> {

}
```

From the Swagger console I access the Vehicle-Resource:
[Swagger console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdGNd.png)

Click on the button and write in the text box the json with the vehicle data:
[enter JSON data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPyOs.png)

As we can see in the following image, the answer is 201. Initially the vehicle was saved with the identifier "id": "60e740935ed5a10e2c2ed19e".
[Send request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cgwV.png)

I access the database to check that the vehicle has been correctly stored in the vehicle table. To my surprise ... there is no vehicle in the vehicle table:
[show database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg2n2.png)

I can make sure that the data in the database application-dev is OK. I don't have any other databases.

I suspect that transactions with the database are not actually being made. This data is somehow stored in memory because if I do a findAllVehicles from Swagger it does return the vehicle.

Answer (score -1):

I have a eureka server running (jhipster-registry) and two microservices that synchronize with it. The Gateway, which acts as a reverse proxy and the Vehiculos microservice. The Swagger console is the gateway, from where I make the request to insert vehicles. Everything seems to work, but as I say in bbdd does not save anything.